# Platform class java.util.Date requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

I'm using a Moshi adapter to get the object from a JSON string.

Sometimes it works well, but sometimes it fails. I don't know why

Can someone help me

```
import com.squareup.moshi.*
import java.lang.reflect.Type
import java.util.*

@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@JsonQualifier
annotation class DateLong

class DateLongJsonAdapterFactory : JsonAdapter.Factory {

    override fun create(type: Type, annotations: MutableSet<out Annotation>, moshi: Moshi): JsonAdapter<*>? {
        if (type != Date::class.java) return null
        Types.nextAnnotations(annotations, DateLong::class.java) ?: return null

        return DateLongAdapter().nullSafe()
    }

    private class DateLongAdapter : JsonAdapter<Date>() {

        override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): Date {
            return Date(reader.nextLong())
        }

        override fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: Date?) {
            writer.value(value?.time ?: 0)
        }
    }
}

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
open class BaseObject(
    open var createdAt: String = "2022-1-1",
    open var updatedAt: String = "2022-1-1",
    @DateLong open var updatedAtTime2: Date = Date(),
)

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
open class FinalObject(
    val appVersion: String = "1.0",
    @DateLong var updatedAtTime: Date = Date(),
) : BaseObject()

fun testMoshi() {
    LogUtils.d("testMoshi start")
    val adapter = globalMoshi.adapter(FinalObject::class.java)
    val objStr = adapter.toJson(FinalObject())
    val obj = adapter.fromJson(objStr)
    LogUtils.d("testMoshi end")
}
```

I get error
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Platform class java.util.Date requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered

but If BaseObjectis defined as

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
open class BaseObject(
    open var createdAt: String = "2022-1-1",
    open var updatedAt: String = "2022-1-1",
)
```

Everything is working fine
why?

Comment: run in android app   minSdkVersion = 19
    targetSdkVersion = 32
    compileSdkVersion = 32  moshiVersion = '1.13.0'

Comment: As the error message states, you need to define a custom adapter for platform classes. Moshi has an artifact for a common Date adapter.

Comment: Yes,I've defined one custom adapter,and add to moshi, `val globalMoshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(DateLongJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()`  the The question is ,@DateLong If you use  it in a parent class, it get error,Otherwise normal